# Community Promotion Ads - 2015

Tags: discussion, community-ads

The dawn of a new year, 2015, now approaches, or has already approached, either way it means that it is now time to reset our Community Promotion Ads!

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- cool game development related open source apps
- the site's twitter account
- scripts packs or power tools
- project or blogs from notable or just community devs
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/1849).

Comment: Shouldn't there be a new one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Community Promotion Ads - 2016](http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/community-promotion-ads-2016)

Answer (score 10):

[image: Help build a 3D graphics knowledge base here on Stack Exchange!]

Comment: Help create a dedicated 3D graphics community here on Stack Exchange. Get answers to all your 3D problems.

Answer (score 9):

[image: Help this community grow -- follow us on twitter!]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting.

Answer (score 9):

[image: Programming Puzzles & Code Golf Stack Exchange]

Comment: Courtesy of [@squeamishossifrage](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1372/3808) from PPCG. (This ad replaces the ads from last year, in order to add a bit of variety.)

Answer (score 8):

[image]

Answer (score 6):

[image: Support the FIRST Robotics proposal on Area51.SE!]

Answer (score 3):

[image: Open Sourcing a game? Check out Open Source SE!]

Answer (score 2):

[image: FreeGameDev Forums]

Answer (score 2):

[image: Be prepared at your station! Be prepared with Hardware Recs!]

Comment: It's a bit big isn't it. "The image that you create must be 220 x 250 pixels"

Comment: @Noctrine That's not an issue. The image will display well on retina screens, and it scales down nicely for normal screens. There's no issue with it, and it's allowed. They seem to be allowed as well: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247063/do-the-double-size-retina-screen-community-ads-work-on-all-sites The imaged that is displayed is 220x250, which might be confusing, but the image is fine :)

Answer (score 1):

[image: Movies & TV Stack Exchange]

Answer (score -1):

[image: Support the Game mechanics proposal on Area 51.]